# Which is better: has_one(single column table) or a string column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

Suppose I have a table called `cities` (id, name) and another called `people` (id, name, city_id).

Now, you can add as many cities as you want, without any kind of limit, so, in this situation, wouldn't it be better to have the `city` column inside `people` and when I want to get the different cities I can just call `DISTINCT`?

Is the **complexity** I save better than the **flexibility** I lose?

Are the **joins** I save better than the **distinct** I have to use?

Setting the `city` column as index, would it be as fast as lookin up the `ID` in another table?

I must say that in the application I'm working on I have around 5 tables of this kind, so it's, like, a lot of joins.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT will work reasonably well if all your users have different cities.  However, the more people you have from the same city the higher the overhead of not separating the data. Best case optimization would be a unique scan on the the index for the cities column.

Putting the city column in the people table can also slow certain access requests to the people table.

The complexity can make maintaining the data quality of your cities table.  Assuming the appropriate metadata is available it is reasonably simple to validate new cities which have been added.  The allows you clean up issues like having the cities 'Newyork', 'new york', 'New York', and 'new York'

The question of which approach will be faster really depends on the application.  If city is always required when accessing a person's record, putting the city in person record might be faster.  If you frequently need a list of cities, then having them in a separate table is better.

Having the extra tables may make your queries a little more complex.  However, you will likely gain significant data quality.  The flexibility you get by putting the city column in the people table will likely be at the expense of data quality.

Your database designer appears to have done a good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can always cache the cities table.  if you use a string you lose object orientation.  Lets say you want an abbreviation for cities.  or a city has_many zip_codes... or city has_many area_codes.  Now you will have a pain upgrading your app.

you can always do something like this to lose the extra query...

```
def city_name
  Rails.cache.fetch("city-#{city_id}-name", :expires_in => 1.days) do
    city.name
  end
end
```

also you should probably use belongs_to rather than has_one